# Android-NDK r10d build error

Tags: android, android-ndk

Android Studio 1.1.0, android-ndk-r10d.

Trying to build a simple [app](https://codeload.github.com/mpospelov/android-studio-ndk-hello-world/zip/master), but get an error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\Android\android-ndk-r10d\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
BUILD FAILED
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I would suggest to run same **ndk-build** from command line, and check the console output.

Comment: How can I do it? Terminal doesn't work correctly, I'm trying to write something, but nothing happens.

Comment: **START** /Run/cmd, switch to the directory `src\main` and run the command `D:\Android\android-ndk-r10d\ndk-build.cmd`.

Comment: Console output: http://imgur.com/afOuIt6

Comment: There are no errors in your screenshot. Does gradle still complain?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know why, but it worked. Now gives another error:  http://imgur.com/DlMLqbu Maybe I will solve it myself, I will try